# how to make getOpenFileName remember last opening path?

Tags: python, pyqt, qfiledialog

According to getOpenFileName instructions:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), 
                                          "/home",
                                          tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
```

How can I make the dialog remember the path the last time when I close it?

and what does the tr mean in the `tr("Open File")`?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you omit the `dir` argument (or pass in an empty string), the dialog should remember the last directory:

```
filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
               parent, 'Open File', '', 'Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)')
```

The [tr](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#tr) function is used for translating user-visible strings. You can omit it if you won't ever be providing translations for your application.

**EDIT**:

It seems that the start directory may not be automatically remembered on all platforms/desktops, depending on whether you use the native dialog or not. If Qt's built-in dialog is used, the start directory should always be automatically remebered on all platforms (even between invokations of the application). To try the non-native dialog, do:

```
filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
               parent, 'Open File', '', 'Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)',
               None, QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [QFileDialog constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#QFileDialog), which will *always* create a non-native dialog:

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(parent)
dialog.setWindowTitle('Open File')
dialog.setNameFilter('Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)')
dialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
    filename = dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but it doesn't work. It gives me this: TypeError: argument 3 of QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() has an invalid type. I am using PyQt4, forget to say.

Comment: @liaozd. Sorry, `None` will only work with Python3 - use an empty string instead (works with both Python2 and Python3).

Comment: yes I am using python2.7 and PyQt4 in my CentOS6.4, but the empty string way seems do not work for me, it always open the python script folder as the default position.

Comment: @liaozd. What desktop do you use? It's possible that my original solution won't work on all platforms/desktops - see my updated answer for other options.

Comment: I am using the Linux CentOS 6.4, thanks for your help. this part works "None, QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)".